# #1452 MySQL помогите

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Ошибка
SQL запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE `place` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`how`) 
REFERENCES `soc_pasport`.`place_how`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Ответ MySQL: Документация

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`soc_pasport`.`#sql-19e0_10a`, CONSTRAINT
`#sql-19e0_10a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`how`) REFERENCES `place_how`
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: `select * from place where how not in (select id from place_how)` выдает хотя бы одну запись?

Comment: нет не выдает..

Comment: А типы полей совпадают? А оба поля Not Null?

Comment: да совпадают. да not null

Comment: 1452 - это ошибка именно данных. То есть по структуре у сервера претензий нет, а вот текущее наполнение проверку не проходит. Рекомендую создать дубликаты таблиц (пустые - `CREATE TABLE t2 LIKE t1`), добавить эту связь, после чего загрузить в них данные из оригиналов (сперва один. потом много) запросом `INSERT IGNORE`. После чего посмотреть, какие записи в таблице "много" не скопировались, и постараться понять, по какой причине.

Comment: Да, тип поля озвучьте, что ли...

Answer (score -1):

Это должно помочь

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
ALTER TABLE `place` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`how`) 
REFERENCES `soc_pasport`.`place_how`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Чревато потерей данных.

Comment: @Akina Согласен, но из комментариев к вопросу от `@AsLan` потери быть не должно